# How to import Facebook Like Button project into Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, facebook-like

I'm trying to implement a Facebook Like Button in an app and I just found a good library: [Facebook Like Button by shamanland](https://github.com/shamanland/facebook-like-button).

Now the problem is that I'm using Eclipse and I can't figure out how to import this project correctly in order to use it in the app.
Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: thats a gradle build project  need to modify a bit to import in eclipse

Comment: i hv converted in eclipse project

Comment: check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26402848/1891118

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That project uses the `gradle` build system, but eclipse uses the `ant` system.

Google is leaving `ant` and migrating to the new `gradle` system which is used with their new Android Studio IDE. Most of the new libraries also are migrating to `gradle` due to easy dependency management.

This is a good time to migrate your project to [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html).

Download it and when you import your project, it will automatically convert it to `gradle`.

Then you can easily add `gradle` libraries to your project's `build.gradle`, and it will take care of downloading and maintaining them.

For this particular library, you have to add the following to your `build.gradle`:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.shamanland:facebook-like-button:0.1.6'
}
```

You can also download the `Gradle` plugin for Eclipse, but it may not be fully compatible with ADT. It's better to use the Android Studio and avoid the headache.

[More Info Here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may download compiled `aar` file from the [Maven Cental](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.shamanland%7Cfacebook-like-button%7C0.1.8%7Caar).

Just import this `aar` into your Eclipse project as standalone library.